# Finding out how often a phrase is used on facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api, status, metrics, social-media

I'm doing some research on the role of social media in social awareness campaigns, and want to be able to find out how many people mentioned a phrase in their status updates over a time period. Pretty much a 'Google Trends' for status updates instead of Google search queries. Is there a way to get that kind of data? I can imagine it'd be a pretty intensive query given the number of possible results, especially over longer time periods, so I don't think they'd let anyone just craft up a curl to do that and go to town. Is there a way for me to run that kind of metric?

Answer (score 0):

Just poll the `http://graph.facebook.com/search` endpoint

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE`

In your case

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=watermelon&type=post`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/